# Google Analytics showing less monthly visitors than yesterday

Tags: google-analytics, traffic

I typically use GA by selecting the first day of the month then selecting the current day and viewing my results for the current month.  At this point I have no special filters or anything, just the vanilla setup.  I check GA daily and have noticed on occasion that GA will occasionally show me lower monthly visits than the previous day checked.  It's as if GA is revising it's data first showing me X monthly visitors only to change those numbers to X-Y the next day.

Yesterday I got a decent spike in traffic and was happily watching new visits/page counts come in from a specific domain that linked to my site.  I also have regular users that access my site directly.  I wake up this morning and all the traffic from yesterday is gone.  I am seeing data come in for today, but yesterday shows 0 visitors and 0 page views.  Any idea what is happening?

Answer (score -1):

[SFMPE] In the last two days I also noticed similar changes. On Wednesday I saw 1600 visitors in GA for Tuesday, but on Thursday only 600 for Tuesday. On Thursday I saw 1600 visitors for Wednesday, today (Firday) only 600. Today (Friday) I see 1600 visitors for yesterday. I guess tomorrow it will change to 600 again. Meanwhile Awstats shows increase in traffic: 1200 on Tuesday, 2400 on Wednesday, 4000 on Thursday. I also noticed some sort of robot activity (spammy meaningless comments-flow with links) so I think it's up to that, and GA just made some second cleaning.

Not sure.